# IsEnabled TextBox style. Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, textbox, styles

I'm trying to prevent textbox from fading out when it is disabled.
So i'm trying to do it in IsEnabledChanged event handler like this:

```
private void AssociatedObjectOnIsEnabledChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var border = FindVisualChildByName<Border>(AssociatedObject, "DisabledVisual");
            if (!(bool) e.NewValue)
            {
                AssociatedObject.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0));
                if (border != null)
                {
                    border.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    border.Opacity = 0;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                AssociatedObject.Foreground = defaultBrush;
            }
        }
```

So.. This approach doesn't work. Actually ActualWidth and ActualHeight is presented, but Visibility set to Collapsed.

Can't understand why? And any other approaches to prevent textbox from fading out when `IsEnabled = false`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The effect is because of visual states of the textbox ([MSDN LINK)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645061%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

The VisualState Name Disabled causes the fading effect.

I have pasted the edited style by commenting the storyboard for fading effect. All you have to do is apply this style(after editing if needed)  to ur text box for which u Don't want thfading  effect.

```
  <Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFFFFFF"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF000000"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
            <Setter.Value>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF617584" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                    <Grid x:Name="RootElement">
                        <vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MouseOverBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="#FF99C1E2" Duration="0"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </vsm:VisualState>
                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <!--<Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0"/>
                                    </Storyboard>-->
                                </vsm:VisualState>
                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="ReadOnly">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ReadOnlyVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </vsm:VisualState>
                            </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                            <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </vsm:VisualState>
                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Unfocused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0" Duration="0"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </vsm:VisualState>
                            </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                            <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="ValidationStates">
                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Valid"/>
                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="InvalidUnfocused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ValidationErrorElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </vsm:VisualState>
                                <vsm:VisualState x:Name="InvalidFocused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ValidationErrorElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="validationTooltip" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <sys:Boolean>True</sys:Boolean>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </vsm:VisualState>
                            </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                        </vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="Border" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="1" Opacity="1" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                            <Grid>
                                <Border x:Name="ReadOnlyVisualElement" Opacity="0" Background="#5EC9C9C9"/>
                                <Border x:Name="MouseOverBorder" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Transparent">
                                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentElement" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" BorderThickness="0" IsTabStop="False"/>
                                </Border>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <Border x:Name="DisabledVisualElement" Background="#A5F7F7F7" BorderBrush="#A5F7F7F7" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Opacity="0" IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
                        <Border x:Name="FocusVisualElement" BorderBrush="#FF6DBDD1" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Margin="1" Opacity="0" IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
                        <Border x:Name="ValidationErrorElement" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="1" BorderBrush="#FFDB000C" Visibility="Collapsed">
                            <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                                <ToolTip x:Name="validationTooltip" Template="{StaticResource ValidationToolTipTemplate}" Placement="Right" 
                     PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                     DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                                    <ToolTip.Triggers>
                                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Canvas.Loaded">
                                            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="validationTooltip" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsHitTestVisible">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                                    <sys:Boolean>true</sys:Boolean>
                                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                </BeginStoryboard>
                                            </EventTrigger.Actions>
                                        </EventTrigger>
                                    </ToolTip.Triggers>
                                </ToolTip>
                            </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                            <Grid Width="12" Height="12" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="1,-4,-4,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="Transparent">
                                <Path Margin="1,3,0,0" Data="M 1,0 L6,0 A 2,2 90 0 1 8,2 L8,7 z" Fill="#FFDC000C"/>
                                <Path Margin="1,3,0,0" Data="M 0,0 L2,0 L 8,6 L8,8" Fill="#ffffff"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this from CodeBehind, but not from styles?

Comment: Actually i've got a little difference. In my textbox the border name is DisabledVisual, not DisabledVisualElement... Don't know why..

Comment: Did u apply that style to ur text box ?

Comment: I copied that style from the msdn link i provided in my answer.. It may differ but u can change style accordingly..
And there is no need to do this from code behind.